# Regex java a regular expression to extract string except the last number

Tags: java, regex, string

How to extract all characters from a string without the last number (if exist ) in Java, I found how to extract the last number in a string using this regex `[0-9.]+$` , however I want the opposite.

Examples :

`abd_12df1231` => `abd_12df`

`abcd` => `abcd`

`abcd12a` => `abcd12a`

`abcd12a1` => `abcd12a`

Comment: You may use that regex in `replaceFirst`, `s.replaceFirst("[0-9][0-9.]*$", "")` or `s.replaceFirst("\\d+$", "")`.

Comment: You could try  [^\w+\D+](https://regex101.com/r/YMAL3M/1/)

Comment: @Thefourthbird: thanks that one worked perfectly, can you add it as an answer it may help somebody else.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for you reply it works but not using Pattern.compile(exp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might do is match from the start of the string `^` one or more word characters `\w+` followed by not a digit using `\D`

[`^\w+\D`](https://regex101.com/r/a1Wono/1)

As suggested in the comments, you could expand the characters you want to match using a character class [`^[\w-]+\D`](https://regex101.com/r/BarTGP/1) or if you want to match any character you could use a dot [`^.+\D`](https://regex101.com/r/RM533s/1)

Comment: `^\w+\D+` won't match correctly in [`abc-12df1231` or `abc 12df1231`](https://regex101.com/r/YMAL3M/2)

Comment: `^.+\D+` this would be the shorter version that also captures `abc-12df1231` or `abc 12df1231`

Comment: @LaurentMouchart But that does not handle the case with a float value at the end. The original `[0-9.]+$` regex also handles float values. Besies, there is no point using `+` after `\D` in `^.+\D+`, the match will grab a substring greedily up to the last non-digit char in the string. So, `^.+\D+` = `^.+\D`. Also, this solution does not handle line breaks in the input well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, the `\D+` can be `\D`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove one or more digits at the end of the string, you may use

```
s = s.replaceFirst("[0-9]+$", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/81ZhMs/1)

To also remove floats, use

```
s = s.replaceFirst("[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$", "");
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/81ZhMs/2)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a `Pattern.DOTALL` inline modifier
- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group #1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\\d*\\.?\\d+` - an integer or float value
- `$` - end of string.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/ZoYcmr):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("abd_12df1231", "abcd", "abcd12a", "abcd12a1", "abcd12a1.34567");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str + " => \"" + str.replaceFirst("[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$", "") + "\"");
```

Output:

```
abd_12df1231 => "abd_12df"
abcd => "abcd"
abcd12a => "abcd12a"
abcd12a1 => "abcd12a"
abcd12a1.34567 => "abcd12a"
```

To actually match a substring from start till the last number, you may use

```
(?s)^(.*?)\d*\.?\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jIuwNE/1)

Java code:

```
String s = "abc234 def1.566";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)^(.*?)\\d*\\.?\\d+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply it works but not using Pattern.compile(exp).

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb It does use `Pattern.compile` but "behind the scenes". There is no way to match a regex pattern without that :)

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb See my uipdate with a regex that handles both integer and float numbers at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

With this Regex you could capture the last digit(s)

```
\d+$
```

You could save that digit and do a `string.replace(lastDigit,"");`